# EXC_BAD_ACCESS due to PostNotification

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am facing one issue regarding one module let me clear the flow for the same.

I have one customized UITableviewCell.

When I am getting some new information I am posting one notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:KGotSomething object:nil userInfo:message];
```

In view where I am maintaining the table I am initiating a customized cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell= [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame: reuseIdentifier:identifier document:doc];
    return cell;
}
```

now in customcell.mm

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                 selector:@selector(GotSomething:) 
                         name:KGotSomething 
                        object:nil];
}
```

and in dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                    name:KGotSomething 
                       object:nil];
}
```

Now my app crashes due to this notification and dealloc is never get called.

Can you guys help me, how to get this working or anything I m doing wrong over here...

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: Can you check the GotSomething: of the customcell, is it here? Is the method signature correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` and `dealloc` methods are incomplete. Is it on purpose ?

`initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` should contains a call to super:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                 selector:@selector(GotSomething:) 
                         name:KGotSomething 
                        object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and `dealloc` too:

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                    name:KGotSomething 
                       object:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**Update**

The cell is not auto-release after its creation. So the cell is leaking and never gets deallocated. The code should be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell= [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame: reuseIdentifier:identifier document:doc];
    return [cell autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Hi Laurent Thanks for reply.. These two i.e init and dealloc are with same prototype as you have said.. Issue is dealloc for customcell never get called.. the retain count for this cell remain 3. and as dealloc not get called my notification is not removed properly. Though we release table which is using custom cell,I am not able to understand how to release these custom cell.

Comment: In the "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method, you are creating a cell and return it without auto-releasing it. This may be why the cell never gets deallocated.

Comment: Why don't you use the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:" method in the "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method ? It is the recommended way to optimize cell creation and management (See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).